# What happens to marriage on the New Earth

Tags: heaven, biblical-basis, marriage

I think I can safely say that humans were designed not to operate as a single solitary person but as part of a unit of two -- both as referenced by [Gen 3:16-17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis%203:16-17&version=NIV) (see mentions of husband and wife in said passages) and ingrained feelings that appear to be a part of every person I know of (near as I can tell anyway...). However, there also seems to be support for there being no marriage after we are resurrected in [Matthew 22:30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+22:30&version=NIV). Can someone clear up my confusion on this topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting the verse you just cited (Matthew 22:30) back into context will clear up a bit of your confusion. First of all, the question was posed by the Jewish leaders about tedious Jewish customs in an attempt to catch Jesus off guard, as they frequently tried to do. The chapter even goes as far as to specify that they were Sadducees, which did not even believe in the resurrection. Furthermore, Christ's answer that they will not be married nor given in marriage refers to this contrived example (if you look at the KJV translation, it says "they" rather than "people") and not to couples in general. So this verse does not provide much support against marriage after the resurrection.

My experience is that most Christians agree that marriage between husband and wife is ordained by God...at least for this mortal life. The Bible does not say much else about marriage after death, and there doesn't seem to be a consensus among the various denominations as to the state of marriage after death.

Answer (score 5):

Another great question! Marriage is an earthly covenant set in place by God and is terminated when the flesh dies (death). You're right in your assumptions that there is no marriage after we die. On top of Matthew 22:30 (which personally I think is quite plain), there is 1 Cor. 7:39: "*A wife is bound by law as long as her husband lives; but if her husband dies, she is at liberty to be married to whom she wishes..*" and also in Eph. 5:31: "*For this reason a man shall leave his father and mother and be joined to his wife, and the two shall become one **flesh***.". The keyword here being flesh of course. Not only does the Bible speak of sex here, but it talks about a covenant that is bound by the flesh.

Marriage is an earthly symbol that represents a heavenly perfection. The marriage between God and man. We-as the bride of Christ-are betrothed to Him forever. That is the only marriage that will continue throughout eternity. What would be the purpose of marriage in eternity? If we read 1 Cor. 7 we realize that people are given in marriage because of the desires of the flesh (7:2, 7:9, 7:36). In eternity we will a spiritual body much like our current body, but totally different at the same time. Insead of a person that's ruled by our flesh we will be a people ruled by our spirits (by the Holy Spirit). 1 Cor. 15:44 says, "*It (our bodies) is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body. There is a natural body, and there is a spiritual body.*".

In the book of Revelations John pains a beautiful picture of the Church as the Bride of Christ. That marriage is finally consummated symbolically when Jesus returns. There is even a marriage supper! In the age to come we won't be serving ourselves in everyday life, but Jesus. We will fully be given to Him. If we think that spending eternity serving Jesus is going to be boring then we probably have some theology wrong. The Creator of the universe in all His majesty comes and lives with us. He makes His home here. God with man- the ultimate act of humility and intimacy.

Answer (score 0):

HI I don't know if the old marriage laws will hold true.  But I believe we will be able to make a better covenant with our spouses if we are truly soul mates and made for each other.  I don't beleive for one minute that the relationship we cultivated in marriage will simply disappear and not matter.  I can't imagine not being bonded to my spouse in eternity even in the event that one of us should die.  In my heart there is no better match for me out there and I believe that will continue throughout eternity.  So I believe we will continue to have relationships with our loved ones, whether they be family, friends or spouses.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'd invite you to read the [FAQ] as well as http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer

Answer (score 0):

1) In the resurrection it is our flesh that is raised up out of the grave. We don't get some other body to replace it so any covenant in our flesh (ie: with our spouse) will likely still remain (One Flesh).

2) In Mat 22:29 when Jesus said "You are ignorant of the law" he may have been referring to Deut 24:4 which would clearly states that the others "may not take her again to be his wife". So the last of the seven men would be her husband. The the others "may not take her again to be his wife".

3) In 1 Cor 6:16-20 it is mentioned that in the resurrection we are "raised up by his own power" then it says that we should not fornicate because "he that committeth fornication sinneth against his own body. What? Know yea not that your body is the temple of the Holy Ghost". My point is that once resurrected we are are still effected by our sexual union in our flesh, which brings me to point number 4.

4) Rev 14:4 The 144,000 male virgins that will be set apart unto Christ after the first resurrection are said to be "not defiled with women", which makes little sense if our bodies are remade with no union with which to be defiled by.

These are the few scriptures that I hope answer this question.

Comment: Where is your evidence for these points? Point 1 seems very contentious - what about those whose bodies get destroyed? What about those whose bodies get turned into fertiliser, into food, and then into other people's bodies?

Comment: @curiousdannii, Thank you for your question. In point 1 I am referring to the long standing religious tradition that Jesus in fact shows scars in his hands to Thomas in John 20:27. Also to 1 Corinthians 15:52 that states that those that are alive and remain are "changed" and the "dead raised". This would be a strong indicator that our bodies are changed not replaced. I hope that answers your question. If it does not please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone who assumes we will not still be with our spouse after death, Doesn't understand. When God intended a perfect world, He made a Man, and His woman in Paradise with perfect commumion with him...The World was good there. God, Man , and Woman.

As for the verse that explains not marrying during the resurrection, I am sure He meant the title and reproduction.

Comment: Welcome, from a newcomer to another! What do you mean by "He meant the title"? And do you have any Scriptural or doctrinal basis for this claim?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. We are happy to have you participate and answer questions here. This question, however, falls below the par for what we prefer for answers. This particular question is a bit out of scope as well because it is old (when we were first starting out). Please see the [faq](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq) and read the meta posts linked there. Then read some of the newer, highly voted q's and a's to get a feel for what we expect out of answers. Hope to see you around.