# Are there no families after this life?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, family

Currently the Pope is hosting an [interfaith conference](http://humanum.it/) in the Vatican about the sanctity of marriage.  I have been listening somewhat to the different speakers. One in particular, Rev. Dr. Richard D. Warren of the Saddleback Church, caught my attention to what he said, which has sparked a question.

This link is his speech: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XF7cBeDZiM. Near the end he said something along these lines:

Jesus said, there will be no marriage, nor families in the next life because these are institutions created by God to prepare us for what is to come, and because we will be part of it, we no longer need them to prepare because we are there.

**Question:** Where in the scriptures is this taught?

To give some background, I am LDS, to which we believe that family life extends into the next life and we can live with our spouses and children forever based on our righteousness.

Comment: I believe Luke 20 holds the same story. Start in Verse 34.

Comment: [Why is there no marriage in Heaven?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/22944) | [What happens to marriage on the New Earth](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1570) | [Does the Bible say anything about our human relations being kept after death?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15295)